# A point is randomly selected from interior of a square with geom. prob. Find the distrib. of the area of a rectangle, its expected value and variance.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

A point $(X, Y)$ is randomly selected from the interior of a square with vertices $(0, 0),(3, 0),(3, 3),(0, 3)$. $Z$ in an area of a rectangle with vertices $(0, 0), (X, 0), (X, Y), (0, Y)$. Determine the distribution of the variable $Z$, expected value of $Z$ and variance of $Z$.

As I understand, we know that there are two random variables. One is $X$, which follows a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,3]$ and the other one is $Y$. It follows a uniform distribution on the same interval, that is $[0,3]$. The two random variables are independent. There is also a rectangle constructed for which the lengths of two adjacent sides are $X$ and $Y$.

We have a following picture - we choose a random point $(X,Y)$ somewhere in a red square:

[image]

Therefore we know that $Z = XY$, so:

PDFs of a $X$ and $Y$ with uniform distribution is equal to $\frac{1}{3-0} = \frac{1}{3}$ for $x, y \in [0,3]$ $0$ otherwise.

Therefore PDF of Z is equal to $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$ for $z \in [0,3]$ and $0$ otherwise. PDF is unique for a distribution therefore we have our distribution.

$$E(Z) = E(XY)$$
$$E(Z) = E(X) + E(Y) + Cov(X,Y)$$
We know that variables X and Y are independent, therefore $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ and we have:
$$E(Z) = E(X) + E(Y)$$
$E(X) = E(Y) = \frac{0 + 3}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$ and we get that:
$$E(Z) = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = 3$$

I don't know how to calculate variance of $Z$.

Comment: Your distribution of $Z$ is wrong.

Comment: @Aruralreader I edited it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your distribution of $Z = XY$ is wrong. This is a common mistake: the distribution of the product of two random variables is **not** just the product of their pdfs. You have to formally derive it and it is surprisingly involved for such a simple setup:

Since the support of both $X, Y$ is $(0, 3)$, the support of $Z = XY$ will be $(0, 9)$; so for $z \in (0, 9)$
\begin{align*}
F_Z(z) = P[XY \leq z] = P\Big[Y \leq \frac{z}{X}\Big] &= \int\int_{\big\{(x, y) \in [0, 3]^2 \ : \ y \leq z/x \big\}} f_{X, Y}(x, y) \ dydx \\
&= \frac{1}{9}\int_0^{z/3}\int_0^3 \ dydx + \frac{1}{9}\int_{z/3}^3 \int_0^{z/x} \ dydx \\
&= \frac{z}{9} + \frac{z (\log(9) - \log(z))}{9} = \frac{z}{9}\Big[1 - \log\Big(\frac{z}{9}\Big)\Big]
\end{align*} and $F_Z(z) = 0, z \leq 0$ and $F_Z(z) = 1, z \geq 9$. Differentiating this cdf we get that
$$
f_Z(z) = -\frac{1}{9}\log\Big(\frac{z}{9}\Big) \quad 0 < z < 9
$$ and $0$ elsewhere.

For the expectation and variance, your reasoning, using independence, for the expectation is almost correct. You got $E[Z] = E[X] + E[Y]$ which is a silly mistake because $Z = XY$ was the **product** not the sum of those variables. So naturally it should instead be
$$
E[Z] = \underbrace{ E[XY] = E[X]E[Y] }_{\text{by independence}} = \frac{9}{4}
$$ Finally for the variance, you can use the pdf given above or you can use $\text{Var}[Z] = E[Z^2] - E[Z]^2$ along with independence to note that $E[Z^2] = E[X^2Y^2] = E[X^2]E[Y^2]$.

Comment: Oh, thank you @0XLR ! I checked the article on wikipedia on variance and now I think I get it. You right, in case of expected value I did a stupid mistake. I had to look for a while on your distribution - It's the hardest part to get those integrals set up right.

Comment: @mathman12 yes setting up the integrals correctly is almost impossible without drawing out the support-region of the variables and the curves; desmos is often a good tool for that

Comment: The way that you calculate the PDF of Z - it's not a convolution, right? Convolutions are used in case of sums of random variables. Also, $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{9}$ because that's the support of z and we know that it sould have uniform distribution, right?

Comment: @mathman12 $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) = 1/9$ because of independence; if they weren't independent $(X, Y)$ will not have uniform distribution. Also you may be confusing $Z = XY$, the product of $X$ and $Y$, with their multivariate combination $(X, Y)$. These are different variables and have different supports.

Comment: I still have hard time understanding the integrals setup - wouldn't it be enough to integrate the second one? I feel like it should cover the whole support region if $z/3$ can be as close to $3$ as we wish.

Comment: @mathman12 you should sketch the curve $y = z/x$ (choose say $z = 1$) and see how it splits the square $[0, 3] \times [0, 3]$. You will see that the region below the curve splits the square into two parts: a rectangle $[0, z/3] \times [0, 3]$ and a curved region; they need two separate integrals. Feel free to use https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: I think I get it now. It's crazy that there is a site like this one and there are people like you who share their knowledge for free. What a timeline we live in.

Comment: @mathman12 Yes knowledge is cheap nowadays. For instance, I cannot sell my math skills (say as a tutor) nowadays without it being a borderline scam because the answer of any student is already out there online for free and it is not even hard to access anymore unlike just 5 years ago. Even this answer I produced is patched together from other answers that are literally on this site.

Answer (score 4):

I would say

$E[XY] = \int_0^3 \int_0^3 (\frac 13 x)(\frac 13 y) \ dy \ dx = \frac 19 \int_0^3 x\ dx \int_0^3 y\ dy = (\frac {1}{9})(\frac 92)(\frac 92) = \frac {9}{4}$